# Using pdfbox how do I get a certain string on a line?

Tags: java, pdfbox

For example, a pdf file contains this.

```
Name: John Smith
Birth Date: December 21, 1990
```

Using Java with pdfbox, can anyone give me a simple code to put 'John Smith' on a variable name 'name' and 'December 21, 1990' to 'bdate'?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet..?

Comment: with this problem no but I did try to get whole pdf like with the example I gave I displayed everything.

Comment: Sorry. I mean I tried putting the whole pdf on a string variable name 'text'  and displayed using System.out.print. Yup, any sample I could use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already able to read the data in a String then you should use regular expressions to separate the data (one way)

You can find a basic tutorial for regular expressions here : http://tutors4all.net/index.php/2015/05/18/regular-expressions-part-1/

Comment: Thanks! Now I have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

As you have not shared a specific PDF, it is difficult to supply specific code. In general, though:

### Text extraction

You can extract the text of a document like this:

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

Now you can analyze the `text` like any other `String`.

### Text extraction limitations

PDF is a format which is not primarily meant for automatic content processing , it originally is meant to be displayed identically on different output devices to a human. Thus, making the content available in an intelligible format to a program is not required, and numerous PDFs do not include the information required for text extraction short of OCR.